# Check for completed pipeline in Azure DevOps from WorkItem

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

For a project I'm working on I have to get a Pull Request and Repository from an Azure DevOps WorkItem ID.
I'm using the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client NuGet-Package for this.

Now i also want to be able to check if a build pipeline ran successfully before moving on to further steps.

After trying to figure it out myself and not finding a single article on how to do that, I'm just gonna ask the question myself.

So, I already have:

- the WorkItem object
- the GitRepository object
- the PullRequest object

And I want:

- some form of pipeline object of that specific Pull Request/Commit

I hope there even is a way to get that.

Any help or references are apprechiated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on I have to get a Pull Request and Repository from an
> Azure DevOps WorkItem ID.

For pull request that related to work item, I can write a C# code for you. But for the repository, I think there doesn't have a relationship between repository itself and work item in DevOps concept(link commit and work item is possible.).

> Now i also want to be able to check if a build pipeline ran
> successfully before moving on to further steps.

Do you mean you want the pipeline run status related to pull request? I checked the sdk definition, there doesn't have such definition, also no in the REST API. A possible solution is following the f12 to capture the API to get the build pipeline run id and it status.

Just a demo:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

namespace GetPipelineResults
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            string url_string = "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/";
            string personalAccessToken = "xxx";
            Uri orgUrl = new Uri(url_string);
            string project = "xxx";
            int workitemId = 122;

            var workitem = GetPullRequestAndRepositoryFromWorkItemId(orgUrl,personalAccessToken,workitemId);
            var pullRequestUrl = workitem.Result.Relations[0].Url.ToString();
            var pullRequestUrl2 = pullRequestUrl.Substring(pullRequestUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            string[] pullRequestUrl2Array = pullRequestUrl2.Split("%2F");
            string pullRequestIdString = pullRequestUrl2Array[pullRequestUrl2Array.Length - 1];


            Console.WriteLine(pullRequestIdString);

        }
        //Get Pull request from work item id
        public static async Task<WorkItem> GetPullRequestAndRepositoryFromWorkItemId(Uri orgUrl, string personalAccessToken, int workItemId)
        {

            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            WorkItemExpand workItemExpand = WorkItemExpand.All;
            var workItem = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync(workItemId, expand: workItemExpand).Result;

            return workItem;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: thats the part i already have done. its just the pipeline im missing. so im basically looking for some "getPipelineId(some input)" function

Comment: @yst_ I think the sdk doesn't design that.